# Are in_array() and file() compatible in php?

Tags: php, arrays

In the same location of my php file there's a "namestable.txt" file, full of names:

```
John
Alex
Tim
```

I have the following variable

```
$names = file("/names table.txt");
```

I tried to use the in_array with $names, but it doesn't work:

```
in_array($names)
```

I tested $names and I can echo all the values, so it behaves as a regular array. 
I also created an array inside my php file and tested the `in_array()`, and it works with the PHP array. So, are `file()` and `in_array()` incompatible or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Post the code...

Comment: Seeing your code will help, but also check the manual for [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for the proper parameters.

Comment: what is `in_array($names)` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem most likely is, that each line in namestable.txt ends with a newline (or carriage return and newline) character. So the array returned from `file` contains "John\n", "Alex\n" and "Tim\n".

If you pass the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` to `file`, it will strip the newlines for you.

```
$names = file('namestable.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: There is no need for this, `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag on the `file` function does exactly this

Comment: Oh, yeah. That's better. I'm updating the answer.